# для чего нужно ((n >> 5) & 1u)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите число: "; cin >> n;
    cout << "Бит 5 = " << ((n >> 5) & 1u) << endl;
    cout << (int)n << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

что делает ((n >> 5) & 1u) ?

Comment: Выделяет пятый бит. `>>5` делает его младшим (сдвиг на 5 бит), а `&1u` отбрасывает остальные, кроме младшего.

Comment: хм, интересно. Сдвигаем вправо на 5 битов, делаем побитовое AND с беззнаковым числом 1

Comment: @Harry - прошу прощения, заметил Ваш комментарий лишь отправив ответ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n >> 5` - сдивгает двоичное чило на 5 бит "вправо". Таким образом, бит 5 оказывается на месте самого первого бита

`% 1u` делает логическую операцию AND над числом n >> 5 и числом 0b000001. То есть, "маскирует" не значащие для нас биты.

Вот и всё :-)